# Django messages not showing in my html template

Tags: python, django

I am trying show success message after objects delete from my list view page. here is my code:

#this is the delete view

```
class DeleteNoti(DeleteView):
      model = Notifications
    
      def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
          data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
          data['messages'] = messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Notification deleted') 
          return data
      
      
      success_url = reverse_lazy('notifications:notify')
```

This is my html page where I am listing my all objects and added delete functionality:

```
#using this for showing success message 
{% if messages %}
        <ul class="messages">
            {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </ul>
        {% endif %}

#this code deleting my objects but I am not seeing any message after successful delete. 
<form method="POST" action="{%url 'notifications:delete-noti' i.pk%}"> {% csrf_token %} <button type="submit" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you make a POST or DELETE request to a `DeleteView`, it will *not* render the template, but simply return a redirect.

You thus should override the `.delete(…)` method, and add the message if the `super().delete()` call does not return an error:

```
class DeleteNoti(DeleteView):
      model = Notifications
      success_url = reverse_lazy('notifications:notify')
      
      def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
          response = super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
          messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Notification deleted')
          return response
```

Comment: Willem Van Onsem Thanks for your answare. It worked. Can you pelase tell me what is the different between  `super().delete(*args, **kwargs)` and  `super().get_context_data(**kwargs)` and `super(BlogUpdate,self).get_object()` I am confused because all three are look like same? what happen when I use my View name inside super ? I would be grateful to you if you little bit explain. It will help me to understand about concept of `super`.

Comment: @super9).delete(*args, **kwargs) calls the "parent" `.delete(...)` with all the *positional* and *named* parameters that are passed to the "new" `delete`. By remove `*args` and/or `**kwargs` you do not pass the positional and/or named parameters respectively.

Comment: As for `super()...`, since Python-3.x, you do not need to pass the type `super(ClassName, self)`, since this is filled in by the Python interpreter if this is omitted.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem Thanks for the details explanation.